# Why wouldn't my CSS @keyframe animation work?

Tags: html, css

Hi wonderful coders of the world! Newbie to coding here, and even after checking answers to various other questions on stackoverflow, I cannot seem to resolve this simple @keyframe code.

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>blank</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@keyframes & animation.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

My CSS:

```
.div {

width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color: red;
animation-name: Flashlights;
animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-name: Flashlights;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;

{

@keyframes Flashlights /* "Flashlights" is my own name - not an attribute. */ {

0% {background-color: red;}
20% {background-color: pink;}
30% {background-color: brown;}
40% {background-color: grey;}
50% {background-color: yellow;}
60% {background-color: orange;}
70% {background-color: white;}
80% {background-color: green;}
90% {background-color: blue;}
100% {background-color: black;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes Flashlights {

0% {background-color: red;}
20% {background-color: pink;}
30% {background-color: brown;}
40% {background-color: grey;}
50% {background-color: yellow;}
60% {background-color: orange;}
70% {background-color: white;}
80% {background-color: green;}
90% {background-color: blue;}
100% {background-color: black;}

}
```

---

That's it. I'm studying each element and then trying them on my own, but this one doesn't seem to work..

Comment: That's a bit of an odd filename, could you try something more traditional, such as animations.css? Not sure if it would actually cause a problem though.

Comment: } bracket -is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's several things I've noticed. Firstly, your first animation is called `Flashinglights` rather than `Flashlights`, which is what's used everywhere else. Then there are some problems with your brackets. The first animation doesnt have an opening bracket, and the `.div` selector's closing bracket isn't facing the right way, it's currently just another opening bracket.

Comment: Thank you, GMchris. I corrected the faults and the file worked. A++ answer.

Comment: Glad it did :) Consider accepting an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The second bracket is the wrong type (change { to } directly after the div css)

Answer (score 2):

Part of the reason is that you're not using the same name for the keyframes everywhere. Also, make sure to close the `div` CSS class - you're leaving it open, breaking the keyframe class.

```
div {
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxez7ta/)